# Send a Json object to server with javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I try to send a json object to a distant server, but I didnt receive success message. please what's wrong with this code:

```
  function sendSMS(){
    var input = '{"header":"****","****":*****,"****":"*****"}';
    var url = "https://**********&username=*****&password=*******";

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain:true,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(){
           alert("success");
        }
    });
    }
    // html code
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sendSMS.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<button onclick="sendSMS()">sendSMS</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help please.

Comment: You can't due to [the same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) unless the remote server allows cross-origin requests

Answer (score 0):

You have to simple change your ajax call to this:

```
function sendSMS(){
var input = '{"header":"Ooredoo","msisdn":21620117297,"SMS":"Hello"}';
var url = "https://**********&username=*****&password=*******";

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain:true,
    url: url,
    data: JSON.parse(input),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(){
       alert("success");
    }
});
}
```

The main changes are JSON.stringify to JSON.parse this will help you to parse the JSON data into a JSON object, and the second change is the actual payload in which you missed a " at the end, just after Hello.

If you have any other question, just ask :)

Also I would recommend not to send the username and password as querystring parameter, use a POST request with a proper payload and last, if you can go through ssl

Comment: Same problem I didn't receive the success message :(

Comment: Ok, but those changes are required.
Now, Do you recieve any error on the console?
Are the caller and the service on the same server?

Comment: No the service is in a distant server and I have it's url, user and password. and I have error in console : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: First error means that the url that you want to hit does not exist. Second one, the url exist but something happened on the server, could be an exception. Do not know why you recieve both exceptions, since almost always are exclusive. If the service is yours, and you can/want look at me on github and I can try to call the service on my own with a user/password, rather than I commented before, I do not see anything wrong with your code

Comment: the service is not mine, maybe the user or the password is wrong, I will check. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: No problem, anytime you need